# how to ask for notification permission in android 13 from Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, game-development

I have integrated firebase Push Notification service (cloud Messaging) into my Unity Project. Everything works fine in android, but specifically **in android 13 it is not working.**

From my research i found that due to security reasons the permission is set to false in android 13 and we have to explicitly ask user for the permission.

I also tried to check the firebase documentation on push notification for unity but i didn't found anything.

Now my question is how to ask for notification permission from users from Unity c# script?

```
using Firebase.Messaging;

async void Awake()
{
 await FirebaseMessaging.RequestPermissionAsync();
}
```

I also tried this code but it also didn't worked , please help me

Answer (score 1):

In our project we use [Permission.RequestUserPermission](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission.html) method. We ask for [android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) permission. After this we create notification channel.

This is a code example:

```cs
private static int GetApiLevel()
{
    using var version = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build$VERSION");
    return version.GetStatic<int>("SDK_INT");
}


...
var apiLevel = GetApiLevel();
Debug.Log($"Android API level = {apiLevel}");
if (apiLevel > 32)
{
    // for API level > 32 requesting permissions works well.
    // for API level <= 32 it does nothing and always fails.
    ... Request permission ...
}

...
// Then we create or obtain notification chanell to push notifications.
var existingChannel = AndroidNotificationCenter.GetNotificationChannel(ChannelId);
if (existingChannel.Id == ChannelId)
{
    _channelInitialized = existingChannel.Enabled;
    return;
}

// Create new channel
var channel = new AndroidNotificationChannel()
{
    Id = ChannelId,
    Name = "SomeName",
    Importance = Importance.Default,
    Description = "Generic notifications",
    CanShowBadge = true,
    EnableVibration = true,
    LockScreenVisibility = LockScreenVisibility.Public
};
Debug.Log("Notifications channel initialization");
AndroidNotificationCenter.RegisterNotificationChannel(channel);
var c = AndroidNotificationCenter.GetNotificationChannel(ChannelId);
Debug.Log($"Channel enabled = {c.Enabled}");
_channelInitialized = c.Enabled;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to do it with this code:

```
void askRequst()//call this function to ask request
 {
     if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"))
     {
         print("permission granted!!");
     }
     else
     {
         var callbacks = new PermissionCallbacks();
         callbacks.PermissionDenied += PermissionCallbacks_PermissionDenied;
         callbacks.PermissionGranted += PermissionCallbacks_PermissionGranted;
         callbacks.PermissionDeniedAndDontAskAgain += PermissionCallbacks_PermissionDeniedAndDontAskAgain;
         Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS", callbacks);
     }

 }
 internal void PermissionCallbacks_PermissionDeniedAndDontAskAgain(string permissionName)
 {
     Debug.Log($"{permissionName} PermissionDeniedAndDontAskAgain");
 }

 internal void PermissionCallbacks_PermissionGranted(string permissionName)
 {
     Debug.Log($"{permissionName} PermissionCallbacks_PermissionGranted");
 }

 internal void PermissionCallbacks_PermissionDenied(string permissionName)
 {
     Debug.Log($"{permissionName} PermissionCallbacks_PermissionDenied");
 }
```

and just like this, i can ask for any android permission:-)